# Horizontal scroll for datatables without using scrollX option

Tags: css, datatables

I have a dropdown list at the first column heading in my table.I want to have horizontal scroll for my table. As i am using datatables plugin, i found that i can use ,

```
 "scrollX": true
```

but on applying this,my dropdown list becomes partially invisible. I was wondering if i could do the scrollbar thing using css.Is there any way other than scrollX?

Comment: Use overflow-x:scroll; and you're all set...

Comment: @KunalKhatri I tried  overflow-x:scroll; with other things. But then either the pagination button scrolls with the table or nothing happens.

Comment: Can you add code snippet here for better understanding of what you are in need of...?

Comment: How did you create that dropdown? Share your code to let us help you.

Comment: @HelloWorld, add more specification and what you tried (code about which you are talking)